# Bake Cycles Ambient Occlusion Straight Line

Tags: cycles-render-engine, baking

I am trying to bake an Ambient occlusion map. But when I do it for through the middle of one of the uv islands on the image I get a straight line and irregularities. I searched online but I could't find a solution. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

[image: Ambient Occulision]

Comment: Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange! Everything looks fine to me. You have ambient occlusion under the boot laces, which is expected, as well as around the bottom of the boot where it would join to the sole of the boot. Can you be a bit more specific as to where you think the issue is exactly?

Comment: Hello benticus and thanks for the reply. In the middle of the large island where the boot laces are, there is a seam acroos almost the whole thing.

Comment: I see it now. It looks like that is caused by your boot laces being above the boot surface, then below, then above again. Try keeping the laces completely above the surface of the boot and baking again.